# File upload using multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I used this code to upload a file but its not uploading

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition =
    new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    };

content.Add(fileContent);
var responce = client.PostAsync(queryString.ToString(), content).Result;
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not uploading? Is the client not receiving the post, or is the content null/empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" /> <br /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>

protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
}
```

The status messages should clearly indicate what they are all about, and you can change them to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Its working properly. Only you have to make a folder with name "Upload" in your solution explorer where files will be uploaded.

in your aspx page

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUploadContacts" Width="300px" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_OnClick" />
```

in code behind do this,

```
protected void btnUpload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUploadContacts.HasFile)
        {
            FileUploadContacts.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads//") + FileUploadContacts.FileName);
            this.lblMessage.Text = "File uploaded Successfully!>";
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblMessage.Text = "File not uploaded!>";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: its for all types of file. but you can modify it by adding a condition to allow only specific type of file to upload.